# How to pass URL parameters to ClickOnce application in other browsers besides IE?

Tags: deployment, clickonce, activation

Is it possible to pass arguments to ClickOnce application from other browsers besides Internet Explorer?

I am not even able to launch online-only application from any other browser. I am able to start offline ClickOnce applications (the .application file is downloaded and I am able to start it locally), but I am getting a file not found exception (Could not find a part of the path: 'path to manifest, relative to local .application') when opening the .application file of an online-only application.

Is it possible to run online-only ClickOnce applications from other browsers without the extensions (like the firefox clickonce extension)?

Answer (score 0):

If your client is running .NET 3.5 **SP1** they'll have FireFox [plugin automatically installed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FirefoxClickOnceXBAPsAndNET35SP1.aspx).  Opera/Safari/Chrome support would need hacks (such as copying .application and required files locally).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Could you please provide some details on copying .application files locally and passing parameters to them? I am having trouble passing url parameters to downloaded .application files.